# Issue with memcpy (inside structures)

Tags: c, memcpy

I have 2 structures.

```
typedef struct A {
  INT Len;
  VOID *Buffer;
} A;

typedef struct B {
    INT MyVar;
    INT Length;
    CHAR Message[100];
} B;
```

The struct A is filled at somewhere and I want to copy the content of *Buffer to Message[100] (in struct B).

I am trying to do this:

```
memcpy(B.Message, A.Buffer, A.Len);
```

I am using Visual C++ compiler and it says:

> There is no source code available for the current location.

and then:

> Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Why are your types in all-caps? Are we supposed to assume that they are the same as the standard types?

Comment: Why don't you show a complete program that demonstrates the fault? You could have it done in 20 lines of code I guess. Then we would not have to guess what your code is like.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the `A` that you're copying from really is valid. It looks as if it's a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This segment of code answers your question (***edited to match the description at your comment***):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct A {
  int Len;
  void *Buffer;
} A;

typedef struct B {
    int MyVar;
    int Length;
    char Message[100];
} B;


void mycopy(A source) 
{
    printf("Content: %s\n", (char*)source.Buffer);
    B test;
    memcpy(test.Message, source.Buffer, strlen(source.Buffer)*sizeof(char));
    printf("Message is: \"%s\"!\n", test.Message);
}


int main(void)
{
    A mymessage;
    mymessage.Buffer = malloc(40*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(mymessage.Buffer,"Hello world");
    mycopy(mymessage);
    return 0;
}
```

At the memcpy code you have posted you've used the definitions of the structs (`B` and `A`), although you had to create an instance variable of the structs to start with.

You should have posted what have you done before the memcpy, because from what you've written we assume that you haven't instanciated the two structs, as I have done here:

```
A mymessage;
B test;
```

Comment: I've defined the variables of the structures as well, but didn't post them in my original post. By the way, I am passing the filled up structure variable of A from main() to my function where I receive it using an object of the same type and perform the operation as I mentioned above. Structure B's object has also been created inside my function where I am using it to fill. I tried using the memcpy() format which you gave, and still stuck up with the same issue. It says: "There is no source code available for the current location."

Comment: Then please go ahead and add to your question, how you are instanciating the `A varA;` into main function and how you are passing it to the other function (posting the prototype of the function as well). All in all, post some more code, so as to be ableto help you.

Comment: @anikondemand: I forgot to mention you to the comment above, also I've updated the code to match the description you've posted above. It still works.

Comment: Figured out the issue. I am also passing another 4 arguments to the function from main, whose values were being calculated wrong, which inturn affected my purpose. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @anikondemand: Glad you've solved it!